# Using Make's file function

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to dump the value of make variables to a file for further processing.

So far, I've been able to print the values to the command line using the following rule:

```
print-%:
    @echo '$*=$($*)'
```

Which you call with the command line

```
make print-VAR
```

I really don't want it on stdout, but printed to a file.  The GNU Make "file" function seems like the thing I should be using:
http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Function.html#File-Function

The page jumps into a complex example right away though, so I've implemented the following but can't seem to get it to work: it prints the @echo to stdout, but when I look in my directory there is no output.txt file.

```
printf-%:
    @echo '$*=$($*)'
    $(file > output.txt,$($*))
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: Well, looks like I can just use

```
@echo '$($*)' > output.txt
```

to do what I want, but that still doesn't explain why my file call wasn't working.

Comment: Why are you not simply redirecting `echo` to a file?

Comment: Crap.. good point.  I grabbed the line @echo from another site and thought it was a make built-in and couldn't be redirected, but 

    \@echo '$($*' > output.txt

works.

Comment: What version of make are you using? I believe the file function is very new.

Comment: Just checked the version, and it's 3.82 which doesn't have the file function!

Comment: Please consider posting your edit as an answer and accept it.  This way, it will not appear as "unanswered" any more (which why I came over here...)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two Responses from comments section:

1) To get the functionality desired, just redirect the "@echo" statement to a file

```
printf-%:
    @echo '$*=$($*)' > output.txt
```

2) The reason the file function did not work is that it is a feature of Make v4.0 and newer, not 3.8, which was the version I was using.

Comment: Ga-a-a! Why wouldn't earlier version error out on $(file...)? This no-op behavior was puzzling me too for quite some time!

Answer (score 0):

You can print out variables before make gets to running anything in the shell. This gives you all of them (well, apart from the ones with a space in their name)

```
$(foreach _,${.VARIABLES},$(info $_ is $(flavor $_) with value [$(value $_)] which expands to [$_]))
```

giving

```
$ make
GNUMAKEFLAGS comes from the [environment] and is simple with value [] which expands to []
<D comes from the [automatic] and is recursive with value [$(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $<))] which expands to []
?F comes from the [automatic] and is recursive with value [$(notdir $?)] which expands to []
⋮
```

This is often essential as variables can change as makefiles are parsed.